# Winsock connect() hanging on one network, but not another

Tags: c++, winsock, connect

I am having trouble using the connect() function. My code was completely working before, but now I have moved to a different physical network and my blocking call to connect() no longer works, and just seems to hang indefinitely. Receiving broadcasts over UDP still works fine. Going back to the old network it works fine again. I cant for the life of me figure out why it works on one network and not the other. I have checked firewall settings and they are correct. What could be going on?

I have a pre-defined port being used and I am getting the address from the broadcast. I use recievefrom to receive the broadcast and set the outgoing ip address from it
`ret = recvfrom (bcast, bcast_read,sizeof(j4cDAC_broadcast),0,(sockaddr*)&from,&size);`

`to.sin_addr = from.sin_addr;`

`local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");`

Then for the TCP connection I have

```
dac = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    //  cout << "SOCKET\n";
        if (dac == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console,(WORD)12);
            cout << "TCP socket failed: " << WSAGetLastError();
            connected_ = false;
            return(1);
            }

        //set SO_REUSEADDR on a socket to true (1):
        bool optval = true;

        setsockopt(dac, SOL_SOCKET,SO_DONTLINGER,(const char*)&optval, sizeof(optval)); 

        int pies = setsockopt(dac, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char*)&optval, sizeof(optval) );  

        if (pies == SOCKET_ERROR )
            {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console,(WORD)12);
            cout << "SETSOCKOPT ERROR: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            }    // */
        local_T = local;
        local_T.sin_port =  htons ((short)TCPport);

        //bind the tcp socket
        bndt = bind(dac,(SOCKADDR*) &local_T,sizeof(local_T) );

        if (bndt == SOCKET_ERROR )
            {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console,(WORD)12);
            cout << "BIND TCP FAILED: " << WSAGetLastError();

            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEACCES)
                cout << "ACCESS DENIED";

            cout << endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console,(WORD)7);
            shutdown(dac,2);
            closesocket(dac);

            connected_ = false;
            return 1;
            }

        c = connect(dac, (sockaddr*) &to, size);      // <------- This hangs

        if (c == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
            cout << "connection problem: " << WSAGetLastError() <<endl;
            }

        connected_ = true;`
```

Comment: What do these two networks look like? What address are you getting and trying to connect to? Did you try `tracert` to that address? Looked at the packets with wireshark?

Comment: How "to" variable is declared? What arguments are passed to WSAStartup? What Windows version? Linux?

Comment: `sockaddr_in to;
to.sin_family = AF_INET;
to.sin_port = htons ((short)TCPport );
to.sin_addr = from.sin_addr;`

`WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsd)`

It is windows 7 x64

As for the network configuration, the network that it worked on consisted of one router with just the pc and the device to connect to on it. For this network I have that same setup on one of my two Ethernet ports, then the other network with internet on the other, and the two network devices are bridged in windows

Comment: I dont believe the device will respond to tracert as its documentation stats that it only listens on one port, with wireshark, I dont even see any connection attempt

Comment: Do you use gethostbyname in order to retrieve the right address?

Comment: Try using Wireshark or similar to watch the packets on the network and see what's different between the two environments.

Comment: I did not use gethostbyname, I used 0.0.0.0, which was from what I read is supposed to work with multiple adapters. If I were to use that how would I distinguish which interface my device I'm connected to is on? I get its address by listening to its broadcast. And I am using both NICs on my PC.

I do not have access to the other network as it is several hundred miles away. Until now, I didn't know the issue existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be an issue with VMWare virtual networking devices. Even though I had no virtual machines running, after much testing of various things, I found the device broadcast was being received on one of the virtual networking interfaces from VMWare somehow. Disabling these two devices has fixed this issue.